# Why are files in Cloud Storage not publicly available?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am using Firebase and the Cloud Storage to host images.

On my backend, this is how I write images:

```ts
const bucket = getStorage().bucket('gs://project-name.appspot.com');
const bucketFile = bucket.file(path);
await bucketFile.save(imageBuffer);
```

I am storing the `bucketFile.publicUrl()` in the database which is what clients use to display the image.

and these are the deployed `storage.rules`:

```scala
rules_version = '2';

// Craft rules based on data in your Firestore database
// allow write: if firestore.get(
//    /databases/(default)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Still, I cannot access the file.

That being said, I seem to be able to access them if I additionally call

```ts
await bucketFile.makePublic();
```

However, I don't think this is ideal having to call this for each and every file. Call me picky, but I'd assume that this "simply works" based on my `storage.rules`.

Are my rules wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: "*Still, I cannot access the file.*" - what does that mean?  What are you doing to try to access the file?  Please share all relevant code and instructions that can be used to duplicate your observations.

Comment: @DougStevenson The files are not publicly available as in "HTTP 403 Unauthorized" unless I call `makePublic()` explicitly or, alternatively, set `bucketFile.save(imageBuffer, { public: true });`. However, I thought that this would be realt with be the rule `allow read: if true;`.

Comment: Please be clear: How are you trying to access the file?  Some SDK API?  A URL?  Something else?  Please edit the question with the details we can use to reproduce.

Comment: @DougStevenson Ah, my bad. I didn't mention that I store the `bucketFile.publicUrl()` in the database (updated my question). It is this URL which I am providing to clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase security rules have *absolutely no effect* on the public URLs that you get from `publicUrl()`.  They only affect access coming from the Firebase web and mobile SDKs, typically by users who are also signed in with Firebase Auth.  It seems you're not doing either of those things.

Since Firebase rules don't apply here, you will have to use the [GCP documentation about making data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) and ignore everything else related to Firebase.  It seems like you're asking how to [make an entire bucket publicly readable](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets) rather than just a single object.  The relevant code from that section for nodejs is:

```
// The ID of your GCS bucket
// const bucketName = 'your-unique-bucket-name';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function makeBucketPublic() {
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).makePublic();

  console.log(`Bucket ${bucketName} is now publicly readable`);
}

makeBucketPublic().catch(console.error);
```

Note also that you're suppose to pass the name of the bucket *without gs://* to `storage.bucket()`.

Comment: Thank you! This makes me feel like I shouldn't use a bucket for hosting images for a website.., should I?

Comment: I don't know the requirements of your app and its images, so I can't make a recommendation.  Pick the product that best meets your requirements.